# Minimum cases of n choose k with respect of n choose q

Tags: python, python-itertools, combinatorics, set-cover

I have a list

```
people = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7']

allComb4 = list(itertools.combinations(people,4)) # n choose k
#[('P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4'), ('P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P5'), ('P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P6'), ('P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P7'), ('P1', 'P2', 'P4', 'P5'), ('P1', 'P2', 'P4', 'P6'), ('P1', 'P2', 'P4', 'P7'), ('P1', 'P2', 'P5', 'P6'), ('P1', 'P2', 'P5', 'P7'), ('P1', 'P2', 'P6', 'P7'), ('P1', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5'), ('P1', 'P3', 'P4', 'P6'), ('P1', 'P3', 'P4', 'P7'), ('P1', 'P3', 'P5', 'P6'), ('P1', 'P3', 'P5', 'P7'), ('P1', 'P3', 'P6', 'P7'), ('P1', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6'), ('P1', 'P4', 'P5', 'P7'), ('P1', 'P4', 'P6', 'P7'), ('P1', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7'), ('P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5'), ('P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P6'), ('P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P7'), ('P2', 'P3', 'P5', 'P6'), ('P2', 'P3', 'P5', 'P7'), ('P2', 'P3', 'P6', 'P7'), ('P2', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6'), ('P2', 'P4', 'P5', 'P7'), ('P2', 'P4', 'P6', 'P7'), ('P2', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7'), ('P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6'), ('P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P7'), ('P3', 'P4', 'P6', 'P7'), ('P3', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7'), ('P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7')]

allComb2 = list(itertools.combinations(people,2)) # n choose q
# [('P1', 'P2'), ('P1', 'P3'), ('P1', 'P4'), ('P1', 'P5'), ('P1', 'P6'), ('P1', 'P7'), ('P2', 'P3'), ('P2', 'P4'), ('P2', 'P5'), ('P2', 'P6'), ('P2', 'P7'), ('P3', 'P4'), ('P3', 'P5'), ('P3', 'P6'), ('P3', 'P7'), ('P4', 'P5'), ('P4', 'P6'), ('P4', 'P7'), ('P5', 'P6'), ('P5', 'P7'), ('P6', 'P7')]
```

I need to find in `allComb4` minimum number of elements with respect of `allComb2`. Desired result like bellow.

```
output = [['P1', 'P2', 'P5', 'P6'], ['P1', 'P3', 'P4', 'P7'], ['P2', 'P3', 'P5', 'P7'], ['P2', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6'], ['P3', 'P4', 'P6', 'P7']]
```

That means, any pair I pick up from `allComb2` I will find that pair elements in one element of `output`. How can I do that?

LE: Always q < k

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I need to extract from `allComb4` minimum number of elements with respect of `allComb2`

Comment: And what is your question about what you need? Was there a particular problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: Your explanation doesn't make sense to me, can you edit your question and provide a small sample ```allComb4``` and ```allComb2``` along with what you think is the desired result.

Comment: @mkrieger1 How can I do that? Any idea is welcome.

Comment: @itprorh66 `allComb4` and `allComb2` are just combination of the `people` list. I need to get the `output` result from `allComb4` and any element of `allComb2` must be in one or more elements of `output`.

Comment: What do you mean by "any element of ```allComb2``` must be in one or more elements of output and how do they relate to ```allComb4```?

Comment: Look at `allComb2`. P1 and P2 is in first element of `output`; P1 and P3 is in second element of `output`, P1 and P4 is in second element of `output`, P1 and P5 is in first element of `output`, ... P6 and P7 is in last element of `output`.

Comment: It means the k-uples in the output must form a [cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) of the q-uples.

Comment: If the size of the input is n choose q (i.e. all subsets of size q are in the list), and k=q+1<=n/2, then the size of the output will be n choose q (same as the size of as the input).

Comment: Are you only interested in the size of the (smallest) output, or do you also need the list of lists?

Comment: I need smallest output. Always q < k.

Comment: EVERY set in `allComb4` consists of 2 pairs from the alphabet, and EVERY pair is in `allComb2`.  Therefore, nothing is going to be excluded.  The answer is `k`.  Right?  I don't think you've really asked the proper question here.

Comment: @TimRoberts I don't understand your comment. The way I understand the question, a quadruplet [P1,P2,P3,P4] from allComb4 represents a set of 6 pairs [(P1,P2),(P1,P3),(P1,P4),(P2,P3),(P2,P4),(P3,P4)]. So allComb4 consists in (7 choose 4) sets of 6 pairs. But allComb2 only has (7 choose 2) different pairs. So the question is how to cover these (7 choose 2) pairs using the minimum number of sets of 6 pairs.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want to constitute the minimal number of groups of 4 persons where every pair of persons is included in at least one of the groups.

If so, here is an example of implementation:

```
people = {'P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7'}
people_total = len(people)

group_total = 4  # size of groups we want to constitute

visited_persons = {
    person: {person}
    for person in people
}

minimum_groups = []

while any(len(v) < people_total for v in visited_persons.values()):  # while there is someone who hasn't visited another person
    # take the person who has visited the least
    person = min(people, key=lambda p: (len(visited_persons[p]), p))

    # start a new group with this person
    group = {person}
    while len(group) < group_total:
        # find the person which knowns the least people
        person = min(people - group, key=lambda p: len(visited_persons[p] & group))

        # save visits
        for other in group:
            visited_persons[person].add(other)
            visited_persons[other].add(person)

        group.add(person)

    minimum_groups.append(group)

print(minimum_groups)
```

It prints `[{'P1', 'P3', 'P4', 'P2'}, {'P1', 'P6', 'P5', 'P7'}, {'P7', 'P5', 'P4', 'P2'}, {'P5', 'P6', 'P3', 'P7'}, {'P1', 'P4', 'P6', 'P2'}]`

The idea then is to build groups one by one, by keeping track of who has visited who in the `visited_persons`.
We create a new group by considering the person who has visited the least people. Then we add people in the group who have the less visited the others in the group.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for this answer. Would you consider adding a little explanation in addition to the code?

Comment: Thank you! Very good code! But what if q=3?

Comment: @Stef, I have added some explanation at the end ;) This is not a demonstration why it is minimal though

Comment: I'm not convinced this is optimal. Can you add a proof?

Comment: @Ciprian, we could generalize the approach by considering pairs of people a person has visited in `visited_persons` variable instead of just one person.
But I can't be sure if it provides the minimal solution :/

Comment: This does not give the optimal solution in general. For example, if `len(people) = 9`,  it returns a list of 9 sets, while the optimal solution consists of 8 sets.

Answer (score -1):

```
import itertools, math

E = 7 # number of elements
K = 4 # E choose K
Q = 3 # E choose Q

# construct list
a = [x for x in range(1, E+1)]

# construct combinations
allCombQ = list(itertools.combinations(a,Q))
allCombK = list(itertools.combinations(a,K))

# start iteration
iteration = 1
coverDone = False
while not coverDone:
    iteration += 1
    if iteration > len(allCombK):
        break
    print("Iteration: ", iteration)

    # scan combinations `len(allCombK)` choose `iteration`
    for sublist in itertools.combinations([x for x in range(len(allCombK))], iteration):
        sublist = list(sublist)
        sublistFound = True

        # check if every element of set of allComb2 exists in subslist (construct above)
        for subCombQ in allCombQ:
            subCombQ = list(subCombQ)
            foundInK = False
            for subCombK in sublist:
                subCombK = list(allCombK[subCombK])
                check = all(item in subCombK for item in subCombQ)
                if check:
                    foundInK = True
                    break
            if not foundInK:
                sublistFound = False
                break
        if sublistFound:
            coverDone = True
            break

for i in sublist:
    print(allCombK[i])
```

for Q=2 take few seconds to finish

for Q=3 is still working for about 90 minutes

Any optimisation is welcome.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).